# Creating graphs where the nodes are images gives error cex + offset : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r

While Running the Below Code

```
 # Sample an adjacency matrix:
       set.seed(1)
       adj <- matrix(sample(0:1, 10^2, TRUE, prob = c(0.8, 0.2)), 10, 10)

       # Run qgraph:
       qgraph(adj, images = file, labels = FALSE, borders = FALSE)

    ## "**Error in cex + offset : non-numeric argument to binary operator**"
```

While running the above sample code, i get above quoted error i m using R 3.0.0 and qgraph version is latest one i.e qgraph_1.2.2

```
I need help to work further
```

Comment: Start with this: run your `qgraph` command, followed by `traceback()` to see just what threw the error.  Please post info on what "file" is, as that may well have non-numeric values or be missing entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah it seems I created this bug with the latest update. Will fix it soon. These kind of questions regarding specifically a package are best sent to the package maintainers directly instead of asking them here.